# Fabric js resizer implementation on existing dynamic canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to add fabric js resize tool on my existing dynamic canvas, please check below jsfiddle example for more details and code.

In above example in first click only fabric js selector come and if I will do some changes in my existing canvas then selector disappear because both not in sync.

I think either I have to create canvas inside fabric or create a complete image first to implement this please suggest.

```js
/// (c) Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen, Abidas Software .com
/// License: CC-Attribute

var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    font = '64px impact',
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,
    curve,
    offsetY,
    bottom,
    textHeight,
    angleSteps = 180 / w,
    i = w,
    y,
    os = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = os.getContext('2d');

os.width = w;
os.height = h;

octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';

function renderBridgeText() {

    curve = parseInt(iCurve.value, 10);
    offsetY = parseInt(iOffset.value, 10);
    textHeight = parseInt(iHeight.value, 10);
    bottom = parseInt(iBottom.value, 10);

    vCurve.innerHTML = curve;
    vOffset.innerHTML = offsetY;
    vHeight.innerHTML = textHeight;
    vBottom.innerHTML = bottom;

    octx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    octx.fillText(iText.value, w * 0.5, 0);

    /// slide and dice
    i = w;
    while (i--) {
        y = bottom - (curve) * Math.sin(i * angleSteps * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.drawImage(os, i, offsetY, 1, textHeight,
        i, offsetY, 1, y);
    }
}

iCurve.onchange = iOffset.onchange = iHeight.onchange = iBottom.onchange = iText.onkeyup = renderBridgeText;

renderBridgeText()


        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('demo');

        // Create a rectangle object
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 50,
            top: 50,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fill: 'blue'
        });

        // Add the rectangle to the canvas
        canvas.add(rect);

        // Enable object selection and resizing
        canvas.selection = true;
        canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
            obj.hasControls = obj.hasBorders = true;
        });

        canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:70px;
    text-align:right;
    font:12px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id=demo width=400 height=200></canvas>
<br>
    <span>Curve:</span>
<input id="iCurve" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=110>
<span id="vCurve">110</span>
    <br><span>OffsetY:</span>
<input id="iOffset" type="range" min=0 max=100 value=4>
<span id="vOffset">0</span>
    <br><span>Text height:</span>
<input id="iHeight" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=64>
<span id="vHeight">64</span>
    <br><span>Bottom:</span>
<input id="iBottom" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=200>
<span id="vBottom">200</span>
<br><span>Text:</span>
<input id="iText" type="text" value="NEILLIANG">
```

Snippet reference: https://jsfiddle.net/op6zn7t8/